# Is it possible to update Maven repository index with a daemon process?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I like Eclipse's Maven to have an up-to-date index. However, updating index on startup takes forever. Is it possible to make this operation into a daemon process and let this daemon begin on system startup? This way, Maven will always have an up-to-date index and I won't need to wait for Maven index update on Eclipse startup.

I would like the Maven index to be updated, because I would like to get autocomplete results for Maven dependencies when I want to add a Maven dependency.

My Eclipse version is Neon.